# How to turn Fill Color of Mesh points to Fill "NONE" in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, fill, gradient-mesh

I'm trying to create a irregular mesh shape in Illustrator, which has some mesh point filled with colors at center and all edge points with 0% opacity.

Considering the image attached. I want the cyan color to fade without the pink shade around it.

I tried turning the edge points to none in Appearance panel. But it's switching back to pink.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the edge points to the same color as the center point, *then* lower their opacity to 0.

If you want a smooth one-color gradient, or mesh, when using opacity, the points or gradient stops should be the same color and only the opacity should change.

---

Basically you are currently asking the blend to morph between 100% Cyan and 0% Pink. So there's a middle area that is visible. You want to set the blend (mesh) to morph between cyan at 100% opacity to cyan at 0% opacity.